# Could not connect to development environment

Tags: react-native

[React native use in two both devices same type problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIgtl.jpg)

[Environment connection failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCKqJ.jpg)

Comment: please confirm that a packager window is opened when you run the project?
If its not then you can manually start metro bundler by running this command 
npm start
then try to refresh the app, it should work

Comment: Yeah I'm got it. Nice working.